# Is folder canvaskit part of the output of the flutter web?

Tags: flutter-web

When outputting the flutter_web, the canvaskit [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBtAb.png)folder is sometimes created and sometimes not, is this folder also a product? What does this folder do? And why is it so large?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter uses skia or canvaskit as a default rendering option for rendering web app you can use the HTML rendered instead of the canvaskit but that would affect your webapp quality.
You can remove it from the file but in that case your webapp use the canvaskit from internet either way the canvaskit must somehow used inorder to display your web app and the if you want to save up some space and make your app get the canvaskit from external source you can remove it